# perl how to delete the top level/primary hash key including its values for a hash of hash

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have a hash of hash value I am getting from a subroutine. Pasting the code chunk below.

```
sub check_interfaces()
my @interfaces = IO::Interface::Simple->interfaces;
my ($ip, $subnet, $dscp) = @_;
my %check_config = (
    "ip" => $ip,
    "subnet" => $subnet,
    "dscp" => $dscp
);

foreach my $if (@interfaces) {
    if (not defined $if->address) {
        next;
    }
    %check_configs = ( config => \%check_config );
    my %interface = ($if, $if->address);
    if ($check_configs{config}{ip} && $check_configs{config}{ip} =~ /$interface{$if}/) {
        print "$check_configs{config}{ip} already configured\n\n";
        delete $check_configs{config}{ip};
        delete $check_configs{config}{subnet};
        delete $check_configs{config}{dscp};
        delete $check_configs{config};
    }
}
print Dumper %check_configs;
```

This is giving me output as

```
root@server:/l3dsr# perl test.pl start
10.75.21.23 already configured

$VAR1 = 'config';
$VAR2 = {};
$VAR1 = 'config';
$VAR2 = {
      'dscp' => '2',
      'ip' => '10.75.130.24',
      'subnet' => '255.255.255.255'
    };
```

I was trying to delete the primary hash key, but it was not getting deleted. If I am not deleting, the output would be

```
10.75.21.23 already configured

$VAR1 = 'config';
$VAR2 = {
      'dscp' => '2',
      'ip' => '10.75.21.23',
      'subnet' => '255.255.255.255'
    };
$VAR1 = 'config';
$VAR2 = {
      'dscp' => '2',
      'ip' => '10.75.130.24',
      'subnet' => '255.255.255.255'
    };
```

What I am trying to do is to get rid of this chunk of hash of hash

```
$VAR1 = 'config';
$VAR2 = {
      'dscp' => '2',
      'ip' => '10.75.21.23',
      'subnet' => '255.255.255.255'
    };
```

by doing

```
            delete $check_configs{config}{ip};
            delete $check_configs{config}{subnet};
            delete $check_configs{config}{dscp};
            delete $check_configs{config};
```

But it is not working as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Added Dumper just after the delete, but there is nothing being printed. However, I am printing the keys, and you can see the duplicate occurrence of the key here.

```
    if ($check_configs{config}{ip} && $check_configs{config}{ip} =~ /$interface{$if}/) {
        print "$check_configs{config}{ip} already configured\n\n";
        delete $check_configs{config}{ip};
        delete $check_configs{config}{subnet};
        delete $check_configs{config}{dscp};
        delete $check_configs{config};
        print Dumper %check_configs;
    }
}
print keys %check_configs;
```

Output::

```
root@server:/l3dsr# perl test.pl start
10.75.21.23 already configured

configconfigroot@server:/l3dsr#
```

Borodin: 
    With

```
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper [ keys %check_configs ];
```

Output::

```
root@cdn-fe13:/l3dsr# perl test.pl start
10.75.21.23 already configured

$VAR1 = [
      "config"
    ];
$VAR1 = {
      "config" => {}
    };
$VAR1 = [
      "config"
    ];
$VAR1 = {
      "config" => {
                    "dscp" => 2,
                    "ip" => "10.75.130.24",
                    "subnet" => "255.255.255.255"
                  }
    };
```

Update::

If I add a delete after the delete $check_configs like

```
            delete $check_configs{config}{subnet};
            delete $check_configs{config}{dscp};
            delete $check_configs{config};
        }
    }
    if (!keys $check_configs{config}) {
        delete $check_configs{config};
    }
    print  keys %check_configs ;
```

it deletes the empty config keys. However, if I add it above, as

```
    if (!keys $check_configs{config}) {
        delete $check_configs{config};
    }
    if ($check_configs{config}{ip} && $check_configs{config}{ip} =~ /$interface{$if}/) {....
```

it is not working. I am not sure where it is getting the empty keys from.

Comment: Are you sure the `if` condition is met and the `delete` is executed?

Comment: Yes. It is deleting the data, but the primary/top level key config is not getting deleted, even if I specify **delete $check_configs{config};** I was wondering why  **delete $check_configs{config}** is not deleting the top level key and all it's sub values.

Comment: Can't reproduce: `perl -MData::Dumper -we '%c = ( config => {a=>11} ); delete $c{config}; print Dumper \%c;'`

Comment: Thank you Choroba for your time on this. If you check my second output chunk starting with This is giving me output as:, you can see, even after deleting, it is showing $VAR1 = 'config'; $VAR2 = {}; , which ideally should have deleted.

Comment: Add the Dumper output right after the delete.

Comment: Added the output. Please find it at the bottom most. It is not showing anything. However, there is this toplevel key that is being occuring 2 times here.

Comment: Have you tried `undef %check_configs;`? Instead of all the deletes?

Comment: Yes, but it is not deleting any of the data.

Comment: I'm puzzled why dumper is giving $var1, $var2, $var1, $var from a single %check_configs. Looks more like a couple variables and a loop.

Comment: Yes. my ($ip, $subnet, $dscp) = @_; is getting it's values from an iteration from a previous subroutine.

Comment: I am concerned that you are not showing the real code. What you have put in your question won't compile. All you need to do to remove that hash element  is `delete $check_configs{config}`. There is no point in deleting the `ip`, `subnet` and `dscp` subkeys. Please use `Dumper` on a hash *reference*, like this `print Dumper \%check_configs` and don't protototype your subroutine with `()`.

Comment: Please change `print keys %check_configs;` to `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper [ keys %check_configs ];`

Comment: Do you realise that if you *really* have `sub check_interfaces() { ... }` then `@_` is *bound to be empty* inside the subroutine?

Comment: Update: Showing required output when I add a condition after the foreach loop. But if I give it within, it is not working. I am not sure where it is getting the empty hash from ..

Comment: @nohup: That's much more useful. You can see that there is only one `config` key in the hash, but the subroutine is being called twice.

Answer (score 2):

Worked with the following code.

```
        delete $check_configs{config}{subnet};
        delete $check_configs{config}{dscp};
        delete $check_configs{config};
        }
}
if (!keys $check_configs{config}) {
        delete $check_configs{config};
        }
print  keys %check_configs ;
```